# Scrolling gesture passed to elements below element being scrolled

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I have an element (lets call this `scroll-list-one`), which is a list that scrolls vertically.  It works great.

I also have another element, which also has a list that scrolls vertically (lets call this `scroll-list-two`).  This occasionally gets presented over `scroll-div-one` as a popover.  This scrolling works great too.

The issue HOWEVER, is that when I scroll `scroll-list-two` with the swipe touch gesture on mobile, it scrolls `scroll-list-two` AND `scroll-list-one` below it.

How do I ensure that the touch gesture doesn't get passed to the element below it?  I only want to scroll the top element.

Comment: Did you add a z-index element to it?

Comment: yes, actually, does that affect things?

Comment: Without actually being able to play with code, I would think z-index ( plus position) would provide which is scrollable over the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [link](https://github.com/scottjehl/Device-Bugs/issues/14), the solution is to do the following, which was the solution:

Add `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` to the top element

Also:  strangely this only occurred for ios, was not an issue with android